# Swipe Activity to New Activity (both sides) onFling error

Tags: android, swipe

I want to put new activity on both sides i.e. on left swipe '*activity2*', on right swipe'*activity3*'

I tried many times, but it works on only one side.
i.e. left swipe is working fine, but right is not, and if I copy and change few things in code it gives me **onFling** error.

what am i missing?

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class Account extends AppCompatActivity {

private GestureDetectorCompat gestureObject;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);
    MediaPlayer Player = MediaPlayer.create (this, R.raw.wonder);
    Player.start();

    gestureObject = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new LearnGesture());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {
    this.gestureObject.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

class LearnGesture extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
                           float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        if (event2.getX() > event1.getX()) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    Account.this, Settings.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);

        } else if (event2.getX() < event1.getX()) {
        }
        return true;
    }
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event3,
                           float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        if (event3.getX() > event1.getX()) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    Account.this, Achievement.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);

        } else if (event3.getX() < event1.getX()) {
        }
        return true;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: I don't understand the code. Why is `onFling()` twice?

Comment: @Tej: thanks for wanting to improve questions here. When editing, would you add an edit reason that corresponds to what you have changed? If you delete sentences, then "fix formatting" is not what you have done. Don't use the same description for everything `:-)`

Comment: I don't know sir, I was following the tutorial on youtube.

please guide me

Comment: @halfer  sure .ill keep in mind

Comment: Does your app crash `onFling`? What error are you getting?

Comment: I removed onFling method on event3. do you know any way to swipe right and get to event3?